# Dynamic change Timer service or Quartz

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, quartz-scheduler

We need a schedule job in a Java EE server and we know how to use Quartz or the Timer service.

But our question is, if we want to change the schedule on production or manually trigger the batch, how to do it?

In the traditional solution, we use a servlet to run the job. And then use a cronjob with a http client (i.e. lynx) to trigger the servlet. It's easy to implement and could change on production.

Comment: You are asking about changing the cron expression? You can use JMX MBean listeners that call `rescheduleJob` if it is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I have never found Timers to entirely satisfactory because of this exact problem: you can't really monitor their status or modify them.

What I recommend is a second layer job manager class.  When you call this class, it schedules a Java EE timer for time 'X', and it also records the fact that you want to execute a 'job'  at time 'X'.  When that time arrives, the Java EE timer calls this job manager class, which finds the job, and calls the job.

What this allows you to do is to write an "unschedule" function.  Calling unschedule would remove the job.  When the Java EE timer calls at time 'X' this class does not find any job, and so ignores it.

You can also implement a "change schedule" function that removes the old entry, and create a new entry at time 'Y' scheduling a Java EE timer for time 'Y'. The Java EE timer will arrive at both time 'X' and another at time 'Y' but only the time 'Y' will have effect.

Thus manual triggering is a matter of having a servlet that call "change schedule" to be right now.

The one other detail to be careful of: because timer events are not completely reliable, we implement this class to find all the jobs that had been scheduled before the current time, and run all of them at that moment.  We then schedule extra Java EE timer events for every 5 minutes or so.  Those timers will pick up any jobs that for one reason or another had been left behind.  This is important if your job queue is persistent, then it might be that while restarting the server, it is down at exactly the moment that the timer was supposed to go off.  No problem:  Java EE Timer events themselves have no meaning, they just serve to wake up the job handler, so it can run all the outdated jobs.